# Oozie coordinator job runs beyond endTime

Tags: apache, hadoop, oozie

I have a oozie coordinator job that runs once a day between startime(current time) and endtime(currenttime + 1day). The coordinator job kicks off workflow and things work fine.

The coordinator runs forever. even after the workflow is completed and even past the endtime of the coordinator

```
<coordinator-app name="myCoordinator" 
     frequency="${coord:days(1)}"
                 start="${startTime}" 
         end="${endTime}" 
         timezone="${timeZoneDef}"
                 xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
```

endtime is 2014-05-13T23:39Z but still the coordinator job is running. I have to everytime manually kill the coordinator. can someone help me with this?

Comment: can you please tell me which version of oozie are you using?

Comment: hi, I guess this error was in older version of oozie(i guess it was 3.0) but after a cluster upgrade to hadoop2.0. I am not seeing anymore issues.